# can't add scripts to head with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a script (like below) to the head but it's not working. Any ideas on how I'm messing this up?

```
$("<script src='http://mysite.com/slides.min.jquery.js'></script>").appendTo("head");
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add the jQuery script to the head, using jQuery?

Comment: sorry bad example. i edited the post.

Comment: why head? On runtime this is irrelevant for functionality.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
$.getScript('ajax/test.js', function() {
     alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For $ to work you need to have jquery loaded. So if it's not loaded yet, this won't work.

Comment: jQuery is actually loaded already in the footer. I'm using a platform that doesn't allow editing of the source code and I want to add another instance of jQuery to the head.

Comment: if jQuery is loaded, you can load other script using getScript() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that :

```
var head = $("head")
$("<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js' </script>").appendTo(head);
```

I won't ask you why you would like to import JQuery library since you already have JQuery in your page (you wouldn't use $ if that wasn't the case, don't you ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to append this to head. You can append it to body, it will work, no reason to worry about where it is appended to.